# Webforms Code behind: Writing FindControl in Aspx page IF Statement

Tags: html, vb.net, webforms

I have some html like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" class="summary" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: Black;">
```

How do i do something like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" class="summary" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: Black; background-color: <%= FindControl("pageType").value == null ? "#000000" : "#ff0000"     %>">
```

So how to you return a control value and set the data in the html?

Comment: I don't think you can add a style to an HTML control that way. Also, your question title says 'in Code Behind' but you're trying to do it on the page, so I'm not sure what you're really looking for. There is a way from code behind, also from JS.

Comment: Put a ````runat="server"```` and target the element from code-behind to dynamically add the attribute if needed depending on the value from the other control (I imagine that is populate dynamically too, so you should just be able to key in on whatever value is determining that).